# Inconsistent results between GA API and UI

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to build a JavaScript app that pulls results via tha GA API. However most times I am getting different results between the GA API and UI, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE6IP.png) for 3 different email campaigns. The settings are exactly the same between the two: same dimensions, metrics, sampling level ("Greater precision" in UI, "Large" in API), same date range, and I'm logged into the same GA account. You can see part of my code for the API call below:

```
          dimensions = [
            {
              name: 'ga:campaign',
            },
            {
              name: 'ga:dimensionXX',
            },
          ];

          dimensionFilterClauses = [
            {
              operator: 'AND',
              filters: [
                {
                  dimensionName: 'ga:campaign',
                  operator: 'BEGINS_WITH',
                  expressions: [campaignName],
                },
                {
                  dimensionName: 'ga:dimensionXX',
                  operator: 'IN_LIST',
                  expressions: variantArray,
                },
              ],
            },
          ];

          orderBys = [
            {
              fieldName: 'ga:dimensionXX',
              orderType: 'DIMENSION_AS_INTEGER',
              sortOrder: 'ASCENDING',
            },
          ];
        }

        gapi.client
          .request({
            path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
            root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
              reportRequests: [
                {
                  viewId,
                  samplingLevel: 'LARGE',
                  dateRanges: [
                    {
                      startDate,
                      endDate,
                    },
                  ],
                  metrics: [
                    {
                      expression: 'ga:users',
                    },
                    {
                      expression: 'ga:transactions',
                    },
                    {
                      expression: 'ga:transactionRevenue',
                    },
                  ],
                  dimensions,
                  dimensionFilterClauses,
                  orderBys,
                },
              ],
            },
          })
          .then(createReport, console.error.bind(console));
      }
```

It is my understanding that other users have the same problem too. I've looked into it a lot but could not find a definitive solution. I've tried playing around with the sampling level, or pulling data from older campaigns (eg 8 months ago), but there are still differences, sometimes smaller, sometimes larger. I am wondering if I am missing something or Google just calculates results differently between the 2 systems. And if that's the case, which should I consider the single "source of truth" and how can I support that claim? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

based on this article: https://developers.google.com/analytics/blog/2022/hll the API, just like the UI uses estimates for some metrics. I think even with the same sampling level applied, it won't give you the exact same numbers.
It seems the BQ export would be the only source of 'truth'

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time. I've been keeping an eye on BQ results as well, and they're different too, so I have 3 different sets of results from 3 different sources (BQ, GA UI, GA API). It's quite frustrating. That pretty much prevents me from using any kind of GA integration, and pushes me towards BQ. The article you mentioned has some very useful information, so thank you again!